# Problem with columns in R... Column does not exist

Tags: r, dataframe, rename

I am newbie in programming languages, and I am learning R for data analysis. I was following along a course activity, and I'm having a hard time renaming the 'Company...Maker.if.known.' to 'Maker'. I tried to type in my RStudio desktop,

rename(maker = 'Company...Maker.if.known.')

it kept on saying that the column I was trying to rename did not exit. I already tried different variations of the column name that RStudio might recognize since even the 'Company...Maker.if.know.' RStudio doesn't recognize it. I installed all the packages and loaded them, for good measure, the tidyverse, ggplot2, and dplyr.

I'm not really sure what's wrong, or why the column is not being recognized, I believe the same error will occur for the rest of the columns. How can I solve this, or make the code work?

I will attach some screenshots or the the code I wrote and the error messages for context.

Thank you so much for taking the time to respond!

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)

install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

flavors_df <- read_csv("flavors_of_cacao.csv")
str(flavors_df)
colnames(flavors_df)
head(flavors_df)

flavors_df %>% 
  rename(maker = `Company 
          (Maker-if known)`)

# i also ran the colnames() function, this is what I got

> colnames(flavors_df)
[1] "Company \n(Maker-if known)"        "Specific Bean Origin\nor Bar Name" "REF"                              
[4] "Review\nDate"                      "Cocoa\nPercent"                    "Company\nLocation"                
[7] "Rating"                            "Bean\nType"                        "Broad Bean\nOrigin"   


# some of the error messages I got trying to rename

> flavors_df %>% 
+   rename(maker = "Company \n(Maker-if known)")
Error in `rename()`:
! Can't rename columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `Company \n(Maker-if known)` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
> View(flavors_df)
> flavors_df %>% 
+   rename(maker = "Company...Maker.if.know.")
Error in `rename()`:
! Can't rename columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `Company...Maker.if.know.` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
> flavors_df %>% 
+   rename(maker = "Company (Maker-if known)")
Error in `rename()`:
! Can't rename columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `Company (Maker-if known)` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
> flavors_df %>% 
+   rename(maker = "Company...Maker.if.known.")
Error in `rename()`:
! Can't rename columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `Company...Maker.if.known.` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
> flavors_df %>% 
+   rename(maker = Company...Maker.if.known.)
Error in `rename()`:
! Can't rename columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `Company...Maker.if.known.` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
> flavors_df %>% 
+   rename(maker = Company 
+          (Maker-if known))
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"  rename(maker = Company 
         (Maker-if known"
> flavors_df %>% 
+   rename(maker = `Company 
+           (Maker-if known)`)
Error in `rename()`:
! Can't rename columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `Company \n          (Maker-if known)` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I already tried different variations of the supposed column name to rename it, but it kept on giving the error messages. I am expecting to rename the 'Company...Maker.if.know.' to 'maker'.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please provide a reproducible sample so that the community could help you. Provide your data structure for instance calling `dput(flavors_df) `

Comment: Use backticks, not single or double quotes to quote your column names, which contain unhlpful characters.  Look at the output from `colnames()` to see the difference between abacktick and a single quote.  Without a minimal, reproducible example, we can't really offer more concrete advice.

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not doing `colnames(flavors_df)[1] <- "maker"`, or something like it?

Comment: Thank you, @asd-tm it's my first time here in StackOverflow, how do I provide a reproducible sample? I don't know how to do that yet.

Comment: Thank you, @Limey I didn't notice that you should use backticks instead of quote marks. I'll remember this!

Comment: Thank you, @AkselA I didn't know I could turn a column name into a variable, I don't know how to reference a specific column name. I assume that's 

colnames(data)[column number(?)] <- "variable" is this right?

but thank you.

Comment: @Raphaella: That's correct, it's referenced in `?colnames`. I'd recommend you to ignore `ggplot`, `tidyverse` and such for now, and rather focus on learning the basics of R first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from `read_csv` creating that weird column name with the new line syntax `\n`.

1. You can fix it by just using `read.csv()` instead. (This fixes `Company \n(Maker-if known)` to `Company...Maker.if.known.`)

```
flavors_df <- read.csv("flavors_of_cacao.csv")

flavors_df %>% 
  rename(maker = `Company...Maker.if.known.`)
```

2. or you can use `clean_names` from the `janitor` package. (This fixes `Company \n(Maker-if known)` to `company_maker_if_known`)

```
flavors_df <- read_csv("flavors_of_cacao.csv")
flavors_df <- janitor::clean_names(flavors_df)

flavors_df %>% 
  rename(maker = `company_maker_if_known`)
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for your help. Both of your solutions worked for me. I didn't think read.csv and read_csv are quite different. I'll keep this in mind. I also never thought of doing clean_names.

I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

We can also use partial matching to select the column names within `dplyr`, if we use `rename_with`.

```
flavors_df |>
    rename_with(matches("[Mm]aker"), \(x) "maker"))
```

But the other solutions given (janitor::clean_names, and even better, correcting the data import function calls upstrem) are more generalizable and may solve other problems to come.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your answer. I didn't think to use rename_with, I've only known to use toupper or tolower for the case. I will try your solutions when I try again my activity!

I really appreciate it!